# Angular Reactive Form with signals-based service

Tags: angular, signals, angular-reactive-forms

I have an entity `CarrierFilterOption`:

```
export interface CarrierFilterOption {
    label: string;
    isChecked: boolean;    
}
```

Reactive form defined as:

```
  plansService = inject(PlansService);
  
  planListForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    carrierFilterOptions: this.formBuilder.array<CarrierFilterOption>([])
  });
```

I need to populate `carrierFilterOptions` with values loaded from plansService via HTTP API call and represented as signal:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PlansService {
    public filterOptions = signal<CarrierFilterOption[]>([]);
    
    constructor() { 
        // filterOptions are populated from HTTP call to API
    }
}
```

When I use something like

`this.planListForm.controls.carrierFilterOptions.setValue(this.plansService.filterOptions());`

in `ngOnInit` I'm getting

```
ERROR Error: NG01000: 
    There are no form controls registered with this array yet. If you're using ngModel,
    you may want to check next tick (e.g. use setTimeout).
```

How best to do it? Or signals is a bad idea for such scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not shared the data object you are using, here is an estimate of how it may look, we need to subscribe to the data on the component only since the form values will get set immediately after the form data is fetched, this is the part that was missed, **we need to loop through the data and create `FormGroup/FormControl` for each of the rows and push it to the `FormArray` (carrierFilterOptions)**, then finally run a `*ngFor` for each of the controls and render them on the form! Since I don't have data, I created a mock form of how it should look.

ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormArray,
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { PlansService } from './plans.service';

export interface CarrierFilterOption {
  label: string;
  isChecked: boolean;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="planListForm">
      <div formArrayName="carrierFilterOptions">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let control of carrierFilterOptions.controls; let i = index">
          <div [formGroupName]="i" *ngIf="filterOptions()[i].label as label">
            <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="label" [id]="label" [name]="label"/>
            <label [for]="label">{{label}}</label>
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
    </form>

    {{planListForm.value | json}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  plansService = inject(PlansService);

  planListForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    carrierFilterOptions: this.formBuilder.array<CarrierFilterOption>([]),
  });

  get carrierFilterOptions(): FormArray {
    return this.planListForm.get('carrierFilterOptions') as FormArray;
  }

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  get filterOptions() {
    return this.plansService.filterOptions;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.plansService.getPlans().subscribe((data: CarrierFilterOption[]) => {
      this.plansService.filterOptions.set(data);
      this.plansService.filterOptions().forEach((filter) => {
        this.carrierFilterOptions.push(
          new FormGroup({
            [filter.label]: new FormControl(filter.isChecked),
          })
        );
      });
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-mxhhca?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fplans.service.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)